# BASH brace expansion algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I am stuck on this algorithmic question :

design an algorithm that parse an expression like this :
"((a,b,cy)n,m)" should give :
an - bn - cyn - m

The expression can nest, therefore : 
"((a,b)o(m,n)p,b)" parses to ;
aomp - aonp - bomp - bonp - b.

I thought of using stacks, but it is too complicated.
thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can parse it with a [Recursive Descent Parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser).

Let's say the comma separated strings are `components`, so for an expression `((a, b, cy)n, m)`, `(a, b, cy)n` and `m` are two components. `a`, `b` and `cy` are also components. So this is a recursive definition.

For a component `(a, b, cy)n`, let's say `(a, b, cy)` and `n` are two `component parts` of the component. Component parts will later be combined to produce final result (i.e., `an - bn - cyn`).

Let's say an `expression` is comma separated components, for example, `(a, cy)n, m` is an expression. It has two components `(a, cy)n` and `m`, and the component `(a, cy)n` has two component parts `(a, cy)` and `n`, and component part `(a, cy)` is a brace expression containing a `nested expression`: `a, cy`, which also has two components `a` and `cy`.

With these definitions (you might use other terms), we can write down the grammar for your expression:

```
expression     = component, component, ...
component      = component_part component_part ...
component_part = letters | (expression)
```

One line is one grammar rule. The first line means an `expression` is a list of comma separated `components`. The second line means a `component` can be constructed with one or more `component parts`. The third line means a `component part` can be either a continuous sequence of letters or a nested expression inside a pair of braces.

Then you can use a Recursive Descent Parser to solve your problem with the above grammar.

We will define one method/function for each grammar rule. So basically we will have three methods `ParseExpression`, `ParseComponent`, `ParseComponentPart`.

#### Algorithm

As I stated above, an expression is comma separated `components`, so in our `ParseExpression` method, it simply calls `ParseComponent`, and then check if the next char is comma or not, like this (I'm using C#, I think you can easily convert it to other languages):

```
private List<string> ParseExpression()
{
    var result = new List<string>();

    while (!Eof())
    {
        // Parsing a component will produce a list of strings,
        // they are added to the final string list

        var items = ParseComponent();

        result.AddRange(items);

        // If next char is ',' simply skip it and parse next component
        if (Peek() == ',')
        {
            // Skip comma
            ReadNextChar();
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

You can see that, when we are parsing an expression, we recursively call `ParseComponent` (it will then recursively call `ParseComponentPart`). It's a top-down approach, that's why it's called Recursive Descent Parsing.

`ParseComponent` is similar, like this:

```
private List<string> ParseComponent()
{
    List<string> leftItems = null;

    while (!Eof())
    {
        // Parse a component part will produce a list of strings (rightItems)
        // We need to combine already parsed string list (leftItems) in this component
        // with the newly parsed 'rightItems'
        var rightItems = ParseComponentPart();
        if (rightItems == null)
        {
            // No more parts, return current result (leftItems) to the caller
            break;
        }

        if (leftItems == null)
        {
            leftItems = rightItems;
        }
        else
        {
            leftItems = Combine(leftItems, rightItems);
        }
    }

    return leftItems;
}
```

The combine method simply combines two string list:

```
// Combine two lists of strings and return the combined string list
private List<string> Combine(List<string> leftItems, List<string> rightItems)
{
    var result = new List<string>();

    foreach (var leftItem in leftItems)
    {
        foreach (var rightItem in rightItems)
        {
            result.Add(leftItem + rightItem);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Then is the `ParseComponentPart`:

```
private List<string> ParseComponentPart()
{
    var nextChar = Peek();

    if (nextChar == '(')
    {
        // Skip '('
        ReadNextChar();

        // Recursively parse the inner expression
        var items = ParseExpression();

        // Skip ')'
        ReadNextChar();

        return items;
    }
    else if (char.IsLetter(nextChar))
    {
        var letters = ReadLetters();

        return new List<string> { letters };
    }
    else
    {
        // Fail to parse a part, it means a component is ended
        return null;
    }
}
```

#### Full Source Code (C#)

The other parts are mostly helper methods, full C# source code is listed below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace Examples
{
    public class BashBraceParser
    {
        private string _expression;
        private int _nextCharIndex;

        /// <summary>
        /// Parse the specified BASH brace expression and return the result string list.
        /// </summary>
        public IList<string> Parse(string expression)
        {
            _expression = expression;
            _nextCharIndex = 0;

            return ParseExpression();
        }

        private List<string> ParseExpression()
        {
            // ** This part is already posted above **
        }

        private List<string> ParseComponent()
        {
            // ** This part is already posted above **
        }

        private List<string> ParseComponentPart()
        {
            // ** This part is already posted above **
        }

        // Combine two lists of strings and return the combined string list
        private List<string> Combine(List<string> leftItems, List<string> rightItems)
        {
            // ** This part is already posted above **
        }

        // Peek next char without moving the cursor
        private char Peek()
        {
            if (Eof())
            {
                return '\0';
            }

            return _expression[_nextCharIndex];
        }

        // Read next char and move the cursor to next char
        private char ReadNextChar()
        {
            return _expression[_nextCharIndex++];
        }

        private void UnreadChar()
        {
            _nextCharIndex--;
        }

        // Check if the whole expression string is scanned.
        private bool Eof()
        {
            return _nextCharIndex == _expression.Length;
        }

        // Read a continuous sequence of letters.
        private string ReadLetters()
        {
            if (!char.IsLetter(Peek()))
            {
                return null;
            }

            var str = new StringBuilder();

            while (!Eof())
            {
                var ch = ReadNextChar();
                if (char.IsLetter(ch))
                {
                    str.Append(ch);
                }
                else
                {
                    UnreadChar();
                    break;
                }
            }

            return str.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

#### Use The Code

```
var parser = new BashBraceParser();
var result = parser.Parse("((a,b)o(m,n)p,b)");

var output = String.Join(" - ", result);

// Result: aomp - aonp - bomp - bonp - b
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort! I'll post my java solution too, (probably it is a bit simpler than yours)

Comment: @MouhongLin just curious how long it took for you to code this up?

Comment: @JudgeDredd I think around 40 minutes. Actually explaining and writing down the answer took longer than coding. :P

Comment: thats very impressive.

Answer (score 3):

```
public class BASHBraceExpansion {



    public static ArrayList<StringBuilder> parse_bash(String expression, WrapperInt p) {

         ArrayList<StringBuilder> elements = new ArrayList<StringBuilder>();
         ArrayList<StringBuilder> result = new ArrayList<StringBuilder>();
         elements.add(new StringBuilder(""));

        while(p.index < expression.length())
        {
            if (expression.charAt(p.index) == '(')
            {
                p.advance();
                ArrayList<StringBuilder> temp = parse_bash(expression, p);
                ArrayList<StringBuilder> newElements = new ArrayList<StringBuilder>(); 
                for(StringBuilder e : elements)
                {
                    for(StringBuilder t : temp)
                    {
                        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(e);
                        newElements.add(s.append(t));
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("elements :");
                elements = newElements;




            }
            else if (expression.charAt(p.index) == ',')
            {
                result.addAll(elements);
                elements.clear();
                elements.add(new StringBuilder(""));
                p.advance();
            }
            else if (expression.charAt(p.index) == ')')
            {
                p.advance();
                result.addAll(elements);

                return result;
            }
            else
            {
                for(StringBuilder sb : elements)
                {
                    sb.append(expression.charAt(p.index));
                }
                p.advance();
            }
        }

        return elements;
    }

    public static void print(ArrayList<StringBuilder> list)
    {
        for(StringBuilder s : list)
        {
            System.out.print(s + " * ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WrapperInt p = new WrapperInt();
    ArrayList<StringBuilder> list = parse_bash("((a,b)o(m,n)p,b)", p);
    //ArrayList<StringBuilder> list = parse_bash("(a,b)", p);
    WrapperInt q = new WrapperInt();

    ArrayList<StringBuilder> list1 = parse_bash("((a,b,cy)n,m)", q);
    ArrayList<StringBuilder> list2 = parse_bash("((a,b)dr(f,g)(k,m),L(p,q))", new WrapperInt());

    System.out.println("*****RESULT : ******");
    print(list);
    print(list1);
    print(list2);

    }

}


public class WrapperInt {
    public WrapperInt() {
        index = 0;
    }
    public int advance()
    {
        index ++;
        return index;
    }
    public int index;
}

// aomp - aonp - bomp - bonp - b.
```